# Ubuntu scroll and cursor moves to beginning

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, battery

I am new to ubuntu..(dual booting ubuntu 22.04.1 and windows 11)
I have not opened my laptop(asus tuf gaming fx705dd)  for 20 days ...
When I opened it,  I first update ubuntu after the update, I am unable to boot into windows, and my laptop can't on battery and it's not charging (only I can ON it when it is plugged in)...
After some time Now ubuntu screen flashing at the time of booting AND it is very hard to type passwords (or anything)  as the cursor moves automatically to beginning ( even on browser I can't scroll any where)....
....So I deleted the windows 11 BOOT from  BIOS ....And reinstall ubuntu....but all the problems occur again...
....then tried to reinstall windows 11 again..but can't successfully create a bootable pendrive ON ubuntu (nothing work)...
What I tried..to create bootable pendrive (for windows 11)

1. Used Gparted
2. Used Ventoy
3. Used WoeUSB

What will I do to ..fix it

Comment: Ventoy certainly works. Tried and tested last week. Also your title doesn't match the actual question and should be there only one. If you have multiple questions then ask multiple questions.

Comment: OK... thanks for suggestions.... now I am able to create bootable pendrive,  through Woeusb.. but the automatically cursor movement remains even on windows 11 ... can't even scroll and battery indicator light just flashing some time

Comment: This is a hardware issue.